# Show 'full paid app' features into the lite version?

Tags: android, google-play

I will publish an app that has a free Lite version and a Pro paid version. Of course, the Pro paid version has many additional features.

My question is: In the Lite version should i show the additional features ( inactive, grayed out with a message 'Pro version' maybe ) or is better to hide them?

I don't know which is better for the user, to see how the Pro version looks and only the free features to be working, or just a demo of the app with a separate screen wich enumerates all the cool features he can get by upgrading to Pro.

Comment: For me, when I SEE the features integrated but disabled, I notice them better than a popup that says BUY THE FULL VERSION NOW AND GET ALL THESE FEATURES. So maybe disable, and when the user clicks the disabled feature, give some info about how awesome it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would actually show the proversions features and grey it out.

The reason being,

1. the pro features are all visibie to the user when he uses other features of the app.
2. he doesnt need to drill through to see the pro-features of the app.
3. If the user clicks on the greyed out button etc, he might have done it because he is interested in the feature. There is more chance that he might go for the paid version.
4. If the pro features are hidden some where, there is a chance that the user wouldn even notice that .

Comment: That's how i see it also. I'm a little afraid of the users frustration. Plus, i haven't seen many apps with grayed out features in Lite version. They pretty much keep don't show em at all and just tell you what you'll get by buying the Pro app. Maybe it's something here that i don't get.

Comment: Check the winamp app. it has an equaliser button with a pro label on it. It should give you some ideas.

Comment: :-) I pointed out the winamp app, becuase I was using it the other day, and when i saw that i had to buy pro to use the EQ, i instantly bought it. I wouldnt have bothered if i didnt know that I could get an EQ if i buy a pro version (if they had hidden the pro features in a different page)..